# Workflow to update Milestone completion

Tags: workflow, casemilestone

I am trying to create a workflow field update on milestone but I don't see milestone standard fields in the list.

This idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HS83AAG has already been delivered.

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Any updates on this? Appreciate quick response.

Comment: Any updates from anyone please

Comment: The trigger samples provided there should do the work. No standard way using workflow yet ...